# Why did this TCP retransmission occur in frame 7

Tags: http, networking, tcp, wireshark

Sorry for the bad formatting.  But frame 7, I do not understand why a TCP retransmission was intiated.  My understanding is that the retransmission occurs when an ACK is not returned in time and the send assumes that packet loss occurred and retransmits everything.  What ACK not being returned resulted in this?

```
TCP: 57190 > 6007 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64162 Len=200

TCP: 57190 > 6007 [PSH, ACK] Seq=201 Ack=1 Win=64162 Len=200

TCP: 57190 > 6007 [PSH, ACK] Seq=401 Ack=1 Win=64162 Len=200

TCP: 57190 > 6007 [PSH, ACK] Seq=601 Ack=1 Win=64162 Len=62

TCP: 6007 > 57190 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294966897 Win=64240 Len=0 SLE=1 SRE=601

TCP: [TCP Dup ACK 5#1] 6007 > 57190 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294966897 Win=64240 Len=0 SLE=1 SRE=663

TCP: [TCP Retransmission] 57190 > 6007 [PSH, ACK] Seq=4294966897 Ack=1 Win=64162 Len=1062

TCP: 6007 > 57190 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=663 Win=63178 Len=0 SLE=1 SRE=663

TCP: 6007 > 57190 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=663 Win=63178 Len=78

TCP: 57190 > 6007 [ACK] Seq=663 Ack=79 Win=64084 Len=0
```

Thanks,
Kyle

Answer (score 1):

In `TCP` the `receiver` replies with `ACK#` of the next packet that it expects. If that packet is sent by the `sender` but is lost in the network and the `receiver` receives the packet next to the packet it was expecting, it will result in `receiver` sending another `ACK` with `ACK#` of the packet it is expecting next (in this case, the lost packet). And the `sender` after receiving the second duplicate `ACK` understands that the receiver hasn't received that particular payload (must have been lost) and it re-transmits it.